# How to use Odata in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, odata

I want to access data using Odata, but there is $expand. I know that when using $ in flutter, it will call new value

access data using odata in flutter

https://192.168.x.x/odata/UserLokasiOdata?$expand=HSEOL_TR_Relate_USERLOK_LOKASI&$filter=USERID eq 'jubang'

But in flutter can not show the respond anything

Comment: Could you post your code and print response of your Odata url so we can help

Comment: Sorry, i have solve this problem. with adding this :
The dollar sign is a special character, so if you want it to be ignored you have to escape it with a \

Answer (score 0):

In a raw string, "$" and "" mean nothing special, they are just characters like any other. In an interpreted string, "$" starts an interpolation and "" starts an escape.

Since you want the interpolation for "$dollars", you can't use "$" literally, so you need to escape it:

```
int dollars = 100;
print("I have \$$dollars."); //I have $100.
```

If you don't want to use an escape, you can combine the string from raw and interpreted parts:

```
int dollars = 100;
print(r"I have $" "$dollars."); //I have $100.
```

Two adjacent string literals are combined into one string, even if they are different types of string.

or

When you are using literals instead of variables you can also use raw strings:

```
print(r"I have $100."); //I have $100.
```